# Cannot interact with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

Before you bash me for duplicate, please know that I have looked nearly every other method but none of them have helped. I have a long view in which I have a scroll view.

[image]

The view is 320 by 671. The scroll view has been linked to the outlet "scrollView" correctly.

The property "scrollView" has been properly declared and synthesised.

My code:

```
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES]; 

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,  671);

scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self; // I have adopted the delegate protocol in .h
```

So, my problem is that the view doesn't scroll, and the scroll bar doesn't even show up.

EDIT:

I resized the uiview to normal 320 by 460. I deleted the scroll view in xib and decided to add like this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 320, 460)]; 

[scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];

 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 671); 

scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; scrollView.delegate = self; 

[self.view addSubview: scrollView];
```

OK, now what happens is when I scroll the screen, the bar comes up and I can scroll around to change the bar's position, but the actual view doesn't scroll

Comment: Have you checked if you have set the `frame` of the scroll view and have added it as a subview?

Comment: have you checked if `User Interaction Enabled` checkbox is checked? and , which is on the top view? is it the scrollView or tableView? because I see you have a tableView here.

Comment: In xib file the user interaction is enabled, I do not need to add scrollview as a subview or set its frame since it is in my xib as displayed in the image above

Comment: just delete previous connection and reconnect it....:)

Comment: From your image above it looks like your scrollview is 671 points high (when it probably should be 480 or similar) so try setting the frame as neilvillareal suggested instead of just saying you don't need to.

Comment: What do you want me to change my frame to?

Comment: are you saying I should take the scroll view out of the xib and programmaticaly add it as a subview

Comment: Do you want the self.view to be scrolled? or any other view on scrollView?

Comment: Just start with blank and do all the things properly, hope it will work

Comment: self.view to be scrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scrollview should be 320x460 and your scrollview.contentsize should be 320x671. 
You must layout your subviews "outside" of the view in IB.

EDIT:

Your layout should look like this:

http://ge.tt/api/1/files/4qGbz2N/2/blob/x675

The textview is placed outside the views frame but inside the scrollview. The scrollviews content size should be set accordingly to fit all subviews. In this case yValue should be 550 + 128

Comment: Let me try this, about laying out the subviews outside the IB, could I just extend the view, layout my subviews than resize it back

Comment: Create a long UIVIew in IB add all the elements that are currently in your scrollview to that view. Then hook up the UIView to your viewcontroller and then on viewdidload add it to you UIScrollview and set the content size of the scrollview to the size of the UIview.

Comment: I resized the uiview to normal 320 by 460. I deleted the scroll view in xib and decided to add like this:     


    `UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 320, 460)];
   [scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,  671);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];`

But still no success

Comment: OK, now what happens is when I scroll the screen, the bar comes up and I can scroll around to change the bar's position, but the actual view doesnt scroll

Answer (score 1):

You need set the `ContentSize` of UIScrollView to the **size of your CONTENT**.

Do not set "ContentSize" to the size of the view. The "Content Size" should tell the size of the content within the scroll view.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. The view is extra long as shown in the image, so I want to scroll view to be able to scroll throughout the whole view length.

Comment: Have you set "ContentSize" to the whole view length?

Comment: Have you added the views inside the scrollview? The views that you add should be a sub-view of the scrollview.

Comment: In Interface builder, tell your scroll view to clip subviews and deselect Clears Graphic Context.

If it is the case that you haven't set your content size, correctly you'll soon find out.